# How to add two columns in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, integer, octave

I am trying to create a simple text file from a MATLAB script that is ordered in the following matter that illustrates a classroom's grade throughout the semester. There are 20 entries for the 20 students enrolled, with 5 homework entries, a midterm score, and final score.

## CIN            HW1   HW2   HW3   HW4   HW5   Midterm   Final

### 123456789  100      90.0     80.5     70.6     70.4     40.6            70.3

The last columns I am trying to add in are the 'Final Score' and 'Letter Grade'. My code along with the function added in are:

```
clc
clear

f1 = fopen('grades.txt', 'w');

ID = randi([100000000 999999999],1,20);
HW1 = 100*rand(1,20);
HW2 = 100*rand(1,20);
HW3 = 100*rand(1,20);
HW4 = 100*rand(1,20);
HW5 = 100*rand(1,20);
MD = randi([0 100], 1,20);
Final = randi([0 100], 1,20);
FG = (.2*(HW1+HW2+HW3+HW4+HW5))+(.4*MD)+(.4*Final);
LG = getLetterGrade(FG(1,20)) 

T = [ID;HW1;HW2;HW3;HW4;HW5;MD;Final;FG;LG];

fprintf(f1,'\nStudentID\n\t HW1\t\t HW2\t\t HW3\t\t HW4\t\t HW5\t\t Midterm\t Final\t\t Final Grade\t\t Letter Grade\t\t  \r\n');
fprintf(f1,'%i\n\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.1f\n\t\t %3.2f\n\t\t %c\n\t\t  \r\n', T);
fclose(f1)



function letterGrade = getLetterGrade(FG)
if FG > 90
letterGrade = 'A';
elseif FG <= 89 && FG > 80
letterGrade = 'B';
elseif FG <= 79 && FG > 70
letterGrade = 'C';
else
letterGrade = 'F';
end
end
```

However, I keep getting an error.

```
LG = C
error: vertical dimensions mismatch (9x20 vs 1x1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit1: I forgot to mention. In Final Score, it sums the homework scores, midterm score, and final score as an integer. Additionally, Letter Grade reflects a letter grade from the Final Score (90+=A;80+=B;70+=C;<70=Fail).

Comment: Please try to create minimalistic examples. I'm sure you can strip down your code until there are <5 lines left. At this point most users will recognise their error themself. I can't even see in your question which line triggers the error and I'm sure Octave and MATLAB show the line number. Another point is that you should learn debugging, it will save you hours of fustration. Add `debug_on_error(1)` at the top, run the script again and it will stop at the error. Now you can evaluate the vars at this point and check if their value matches your expectation (in your case their size)

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your `getLetterGrade` so that it can handle vector input and returns a vector:

```
function letterGrade = getLetterGrade (FG)

  score = [90;80;70;0];
  lg = 'ABCF';
  [m, idx] = max (FG(:).' >= score);
  letterGrade = lg(idx);

end

getLetterGrade ([100 90 80.5 70.6 70.4 40.6])
```

gives

```
ans = AABCCF
```

I wouldn't add this to T, but instead use a cell array or even better a struct array or a separate vector in your print function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll want to use a syntax like this for your joining of the 2 new columns, using the var = [ new element] style.

```
octave:1> g = [1 2 3 4 5]

g =   1   2   3   4   5

octave:2> x = 6

x =  6

octave:3> l = [g x]

l =  1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code, most notably (1) `LG` is a scalar (of size 1x1), (2) you cannot concatenate numeric and cell arrays, and (3) the format string passed to fprintf are malformed. This code corrects these issues:

```
% initialize grades
N = 20;
ID = randi([100000000 999999999], 1, N);
HW1 = 100*rand(1, N);
HW2 = 100*rand(1, N);
HW3 = 100*rand(1, N);
HW4 = 100*rand(1, N);
HW5 = 100*rand(1, N);
MD = randi([0 100], 1, N);
Final = randi([0 100], 1, N);
FG = (.2*(HW1+HW2+HW3+HW4+HW5))+(.4*MD)+(.4*Final);

% calculate letter grades
LG = repmat({'F'}, size(FG));
I = FG > 90;            LG(I) = repmat({'A'}, sum(I), 1);
I = FG <= 89 & FG > 80; LG(I) = repmat({'B'}, sum(I), 1);
I = FG <= 79 & FG > 70; LG(I) = repmat({'C'}, sum(I), 1);

% write to file
T = cat(1, ...
    num2cell([ID ; HW1 ; HW2 ; HW3 ; HW4 ; HW5 ; MD ; Final ; FG]), ...
    LG);
f1 = fopen('grades.txt', 'w');
fprintf(f1, 'StudentID\tHW1\tHW2\tHW3\tHW4\tHW5\tMidterm\tFinal\tFinal    Grade\tLetter Grade\t\n');
fprintf(f1, '%i\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.2f\t%c\t\n', T{:});
fclose(f1);
```